# After automatic update of Ubuntu Studio 22.04, I can't type my password on Plasma login screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, 22.04, kde

System:

CPU: Intel i7 7700K @ 4.5GHz

GPU: Asus STRIX GTX 1060 6gb OC (Republic of Gamers)

Ram: Gskill 16GB DDR4

Monitor: Acer 27" 144 Hz

Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS on Samsung EVO 250GB SSD
Fresh installation on 3/11/2024.  The only additional things I installed were Steam, Overwatch 2, ckb-next (Corsair mouse & keyboard software) and Nvidia graphics drivers (535 was the most current available driver for my card).

Everything worked fine 2 days ago (3/11/2024).  I didn't boot on 3/12, then on 3/13 I accepted the latest automatic updates.  They installed successfully, but after rebooting I was unable to type my password into the Plasma login screen.  I can move the mouse cursor but cannot click anything.  Keyboard is lit but does not respond.

If I reboot again and select the previous kernel version from the grub menu then I can log in, but Overwatch gets poor framerate - 2 days ago I was holding 144 fps nearly constantly, now it dips into the 30s.

There is a new driver available for my card, the Nvidia 545 driver, and I did install that after logging in with the previous kernel version.

When I type

```
nvidia-smi
```

it returns "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

To be sure, I typed

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:545
```

and that returns "All the available drivers are already installed."

SO the actual question: Should I mess with this, or hope for an update to Ubuntu in the near future that may correct it?  I haven't seen this problem in my searches, but apologies if I missed it somewhere.  I'm happy to answer questions if info is missing.

Comment: It happens sometimes to me too, that I can't type in my password in the login screen in Ubuntustudio 22.04. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` to switch to a TTY, login with your username and password and then run `sudo systemctl restart sddm`. Usually it works then correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm a bonehead.  I had to not only uninstall the old nvidia driver, but also autoremove and clean.  Then install the new nvidia driver.

Boot previous working kernel from grub boot menu. Then type:

```
sudo apt --purge remove nvidia-driver-535
```

*Replace  "nvidia-driver-535" with the driver you're removing.

```
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt clean
```

Then install the current graphics driver and reboot using newest kernel from grub menu.